# ASP.NET MVC - posting back only a half of typed view's model?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Let's say you're developing your own stackoverflow in ASP.NET MVC :-)

You'd like to have a functionality to answer questions. So, the view should contain original question details (title, text, etc) and it should also contain the form to submit the answer. In order to render the view, you should provide both original question object and new empty answer object. You then want only answer to be posted back.

How would you define the type for this view? Would you implement a view model specific for this view that would contain both the question and an empty answer? What's the common approach here?

Ideas I have are:

1. Using a special view model object that contains both question and answer. View is bound to this object. When rendering the view, question details are used. When posting back, the object I get at controller only has answer-related fields populated.
2. Using `ViewBag` to pass question object. View is bound to answer model.
3. ?

(no AJAX please, just the very basic scenario)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't make much sense.  Your question would not be posted back because only form controls are posted, such as inputs, button values, etc.. Your question is just html text, and does not get posted.

Comment: So, what's the answer? Is it a special model view object containing both question and answer?

Comment: You can do either scenario you mention.  I prefer having all my dynamic data be in view models though.  It's personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to return the question, and any answers as your model to the page. At the bottom, you're going to want a form that submits back an AnswerModel with a given question ID.

You might create a default AnswerModel that gets passed down when you render the view, but you're not going to work (or worry about) question and answer 'objects' just models. You might create a ThreadViewModel that contains a question and a list of current answers.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is create four Interfaces:

```
public IQuestionDetail
{
  string QuestionText { get; }
  // Question Details
}
public IQuestionView
{
  IQuestionDetail QuestionDetail { get; }  
}
public IAnswerDetail
{
  int/guid QuestionID { get; }
  string AnwerText { get; }
  // Anwer Details
}
public IAnswerView
{
  IAnswerDetail AnswerDetail { get; }  
}
```

Then I derive 4 classes

```
public QuestionDetail : IQuestionDetail
{ //implemented }

public AnswerDetail : IAnswerDetail
{ //implemented }

public QuestionViewModel : IQuestionView, IAnswerView
{ //implemented }

public AnswerModel : IAnswerView
{ //implemented }
```

A single view (Question/Detail.cs)

```
@model Models.QuestionViewModel

@html.Partial("partial-questionDetails", Model)

@html.Partial("partial-answerDetails", Model)
```

Two Partial Views

```
//partial-questionDetails.cshtml
@model Models.IQuestionView

@Html.DisplayFor(Model.QuestionDetail)

//partial-answerDetails.cshtml
@model Models.IAnswerView

@Html.BeginForm() 
{
  Html.EditorFor(Model.AnswerDetail)
}
```

QuestionController

```
public ActionResult Detail(IAnswerView AnswerModel)
{
  // AnswerModel is only populated with the Answer Fields
  // Do Stuff with AnswerModel

  QuestionViewModel viewModel = new QuestionViewModel()
  View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Very interesting idea, though I don't like a number of classes/interfaces your approach requires :-)

Comment: It could be easily simplified but I like the extensibility interfaces provide.

Answer (score 0):

When building forms in ASP.NET MVC, I usually create two separate classes, one for populating the view (the ViewModel), and another for receiving data on submit.  The ViewModel (usually read-only) may contain additional information required to populate the view, but the data object only has properties (with public setters) for submitting the form.

These classes will have several properties in common, so that the model binding in ASP.NET MVC will wire up properly.  For simple forms, I don't always extract separate interfaces for each view, but if you want to guarantee that the properties match, then interfaces is an easy way to do it.

To do this, you would create a single interface, whose properties represent the form fields.  Then, have each of your classes implement the interface, which will give you a compile-time guarantee that the form fields exist on both classes.